# Ruby: insert and sort numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have to create a method in Ruby which inserts a number and sorts the resulting list.

Input would be like:

```
insert_number([2.0,3.5,4.8], 4.1)
```

which should output:

```
[2.0,3.5,4.1,4.8]
```

With input like:

```
insert_number([], 5.1)
```

it should output:

```
[5.1]
```

Here is my incomplete code:

```
def insert_number(list, number)
  new_list = []               
  position = 0                         
  number_has_been_inserted = false     # Remember whether a new number 
  # has been inserted.
  while position < list.length 
    position += 1
    new_list = list + [number] 
    ...
  end
  ...
    new_list
end

print insert_number([2.0,3.5,4.8], 4.1)
```

Comment: Are you actually supposed to sort the entire array? From your example, it looks like you might have to insert a number in an already sorted array (keeping it sorted).

Comment: Yes, I wanted to insert a number in an already sorted array, keeping it sorted

Comment: Unless this is homework. it's rarely a good idea to compete with the C-speed insertion or sorting methods provided by Ruby. In *most* cases, they will vastly outperform a roll-your-own solution.

Answer (score 4):

> bsearch only works if the original input array is already sorted, which is not a pre-condition. – @pjs

Considering your original array is sorted you can use binary search here. It will perform much better because it won't need to perform expensive sorting procedure on each insert.

This one mutates original array

```
def insert_number(arr, num)
  i = (0...arr.size).bsearch{ |a| arr[a] > num }
  i ||= arr.size
  arr.insert(i, num)
end

arr = []
insert_number(arr, 1)
#=> [1]
insert_number(arr, 2)
# => [1, 2]
insert_number(arr, 2.1)
# => [1, 2, 2.1]
insert_number(arr, 1.3)
#=> [1, 1.3, 2, 2.1]
```

And this one will return new array on each call

```
def insert_number(arr, num)
  i = (0...arr.size).bsearch{ |a| arr[a] > num }
  i ||= arr.size
  arr[0, i] + [num] + arr[i..-1]
  # or
  # arr.dup.insert(i, num)
end

arr = []
arr = insert_number(arr, 1)
#=> [1]
arr = insert_number(arr, 2)
# => [1, 2]
arr = insert_number(arr, 2.1)
# => [1, 2, 2.1]
arr = insert_number(arr, 1.3)
#=> [1, 1.3, 2, 2.1]
```

PS:

> Recent Ruby versions have bsearch_index – @Stefan

Comment: Recent Ruby versions have `bsearch_index`

Comment: @pjs I think it's implied that it is sorted. Or you can sort it only once in the beginning. If you have a number of insertions you will benefit a lot.

Comment: @pjs, I've edited my answer to be more clear about my assumption, thank you for your notice.

Comment: @pjs: Unfortunately, the OP chose to specify the fact that the input array is always sorted in the comments instead of in the question.

Comment: Too bad that wasn't in the original problem statement, it's important info.  On a totally unrelated note, I'd suggest changing the name of the mutating version to end with a bang.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like:

```
def insert_number(list, number)
  (list << number).sort
end

list = [1, 2, 3]
insert_number(list, 2.1) # => [1, 2, 2.1, 3]
insert_number(list, 4.1) # => [1, 2, 2.1, 3, 4.1]
insert_number([], 1) # => [1]
```

The problem is this changes `list`. If that's not desired then use `dup`:

```
def insert_number(list, number)
  (list.dup << number).sort
end

list = [1, 2, 3]
insert_number(list, 2.1) # => [1, 2, 2.1, 3]
insert_number(list, 4.1) # => [1, 2, 3, 4.1]
insert_number([], 1) # => [1]
```

or a "splat" AKA `*`:

```
def insert_number(list, number)
  [*list, number].sort
end

list = [1, 2, 3]
insert_number(list, 2.1) # => [1, 2, 2.1, 3]
insert_number(list, 4.1) # => [1, 2, 3, 4.1]
insert_number([], 1) # => [1]
```

`[*list, number]` tells Ruby to explode the array `list` into its elements, effectively creating a new array:

```
[1, 2, 3, number]
```

Comment: Why not use #sort! to avoid returning a new array from the method? I get that `list << number` will modify the closure variable directly, but #sort will return a new array from the method rather than *list* itself.

Answer (score 2):

A little shorter without having to use dup.

`def insert_number(list, number)
  (list + [number]).sort
end`

Comment: `<<` is faster than `+` in this case, because it doesn't have to create an extra array.

Answer (score 1):

use [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Array.html#method-i-sort):

```
def insert_number(list,number=false)
  number.is_a?(Numeric) ? list.push(number).sort : list.sort
end
```

The above method uses the *ternary operator* which is a short form of an if-statement.

Comment: Was `list.push(number).sort` too simple? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### Use In-Place Array Methods

In-place operations on the array should be fastest, since they won't have to create additional arrays. For example:

```
@array = [2.0, 3.5, 4.8]

def insert_number float
  (@array << float).sort!
end
```

If you can't operate directly on a shared variable, or want to reduce coupling, then you can still shave some time with the in-place sort rather than returning a *new* sorted array:

```
def insert_number array, float
  (array.dup << float).sort!
end
```

In all cases, appending to an array with `<<` should be faster than creating new arrays with the `+` method.

Comment: The method shouldn't mutate inputs unless it's named `insert_number!`.

Comment: @pjs You may be misunderstanding the convention that  ["names...should end with an exclamation mark **if there exists a safe version** of that *dangerous* method."](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#dangerous-method-bang) Bang methods are not inherently (or even just) about mutation; rather, they *differentiate* similarly-named methods like `sort` and `sort!`. Because it's a style issue rather than a language or syntax issue, your mileage may legitimately vary.

Comment: I fall in the camp that things that methods which change pre-existing state are inherently dangerous.  I understand that bang is a style issue, but I like the widespread convention of letting users know to watch out for potential side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we do not need any sort because we know that our array is sorted, and then when we will new number `x` we can put it into array with O(n) time, where `n` is size of array. We will go one by one, let's take `i as index` and our new array will be built like `NewArray = (left numbers < x) + x + (x < right number):` here `left numbers` are that numbers less than x and `right number` are numbers bigger than x.

```
ispushed = false
arr.each do |number|
if number < x
NewArray.push(number)
elsif ispushed == false
ispushed=true 
NewArray.push(x) 
newArray.push(number)
else 
NewArray.push(number)
```

if our x is biggest so that ispushed will be remained false
in the end we can just push our 'x' number

if you use sort it works by O(nlogn) time complexity